# Remove default items from custom context menu on BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to create my own context menu.

When a user clicks the BlackBerry menu button, the menu should open with only my menu items -- and not the 'Hide keyboard' and 'Switch Application' items that are included by default.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
menu.deleteAll();

// add your code here
}
```

Try this out

Comment: It didn't help.I still see default items.